# How to create native queries in Spring?

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql

I have a spring application that should connect to an existing database and just query an entity for existence based on some attributes.

I don't want to create a `@Entity` class for this. But I still want to use the spring managed `EntityManager` etc.

When using `Spring`, what is the best approach to just query a `select` for that entity? Using `em.createNamedQuery(QUERY);` with `String QUERY = "SELECT count(*) from my_table where username =: username AND email := email)";`?

Answer (score 1):

Answers from @predrag-maric and @pL4Gu33 are both correct but if you use JPA in your project (for example, Hibernate) you might consider using  [`@NamedNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) annotation as well.

More [about named native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-query-native).

Comment: But can I use named native query without having an `@Entity` class? (which is the case as written in my initial post).

Comment: I'm afraid you have to; from doccumentation: `The NamedNativeQuery annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped superclass.` If you really don't want a `@Entity` you should use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`

Answer (score 1):

simple example of native query

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

public String test(Integer id)
{
Query query =   em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name FROM Accounts  where id=?");
query.setParameter(1,id);
return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `em.createNativeQuery(QUERY)`. Also, you'll have to use positional parameters (`?1`) instead of named parameters (`:email`), because only positional parameters are supported by JPA in native queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method from entitymanager. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29